# Get HTML tag sets using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get tag sets from html, and wanted to do it via Regex, I don't know if it's possible, but I'm adopting this template:

```
<p>
   this is a paragraph.
   do not say. (¬¬)
</p>

<p>
   this is a paragraph.
   do not say. (¬¬)
</p>
```

I wanted to do like this model

[image]

I already tried to do [this](https://regex101.com/r/qg3Qk0/1):

```
\<p\>.*\<\/p\>
```

But it doesn't work.

I will use the result of this regex in C# with the class:

```
MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches("input", "pattern");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5101046](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5101046)

Comment: I'm not getting with the link examples :(

Comment: `var results = Regex.Matches("input", @"<p>.*?</p>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);`